# Send data to Vue.js frontend using express.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, vue.js

i am using Vue.js as Frontend and Express.js as Backend.

My Server.js looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.listen(80);
```

When i render the index.html which is in the dist folder, i would like to send some data to the frontend

Comment: The most straightforward way to _send some data to the frontend_ is to request it from the front-end.

Comment: How can i do that? Sorry for the stupid question, i am stil learning :/

Ps: i would like to get the data from a database

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: As Kevin said, using XMLHttpRequest is the most straightforward, there is something called ServerSide rendering as well, in which you get all your data and build it into the HTML that you return, but that's a bit more advanced, and from a cursory look it appears to be a fairly complex topic particularly with Vue.  There are other templating engines that work with express fairly well (Jade/Pug, Nunjucks, etc)

Read up on "AJAX" in the front end for additional study.

Comment: Use [Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build) for SSR with Vue.